# CHtmlEditCtrl - How do I get the edit control to wrap?

Tags: mfc

The `CHtmlEditCtrl` `Create` method says it ignores the `dwStyle` parameter anyway.

HTML is supposed to flow/wrap by default.  There should be a call/style to make it wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired behavior is a CSS style sheet behavior, which makes sense.

The style applies to inline elements only, and is `overflow-wrap`.

HOWEVER, this is MFC `CHtmlEditCtrl`, hence Internet Explorer, and it does not support that style, but it DOES support the non-standard name `word-wrap`.  The standard value of `break-word` does what I need.

So this does what I want:

```
CComBSTR bszStyle("p {margin:0}\nbody {word-wrap: break-word; font-family: \"Arial\"}");
m_HtmlEdit.GetDHtmlDocument(&pDoc);
pDoc->createStyleSheet(CComBSTR(""), 0, &pStyle);
pStyle->put_cssText(bszStyle);
```

Comment: Follow up - I am seeing the call to `createStyleSheet` fail early in the creation of my dialog on older O/S's and PCs.  If I peek/pump messages for a little BEFORE trying the call to `createStyleSheet`, it does not fail.  Need to test return from `createStyleSheet` and existence of `pStyle`.